# ArgumentException Unhandled

Tags: c#

The following portion of my code was working perfectly fine until I restarted my computer and now it is giving me the error of the `ArgumentException` was unhandled with this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Invalid value for key 'integrated security'

```
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=M2192822\SHIFTREPORTS;Initial Catalog=ShiftReports;Integrated Security=ture");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From [All of Production] where Tool ='" + MoldText.Text + "' and [Internal Part Number] ='" + IPNText.Text + "'", con);
    DataTable dta = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dta);
    MessageBox.Show("Part or Mold Number is Incorrect");
}

if (dta.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "1")
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, `ture` is not a valid value for `Integrated Security`. You should use `Integrated Security=true`.

The code has other, more serious issues. First, the connection isn't closed. Second, you are creating a SQL statement using string concatenation, which is a sure way to expose yourself to SQL injection attacks. Imagine what would happen if a user entered `1';drop table Products;--`

Properly closing the connection and using a parameterized query is actually easier than string concatenation:

```
var connString = @"Data Source=M2192822\SHIFTREPORTS;Initial Catalog=ShiftReports;Integrated Security=true";
var query="Select Count(*) From [All of Production] where Tool = @tool and [Internal Part Number] = @part";
DataTable dta = new DataTable();

using(var con = new new SqlConnection(connString))
using(var sda=new SqlDataAdapter(query, con)
{
     var cmdParameters=sda.SelectCommand.Parameters;
     parameters.AddWithValue("@tool",MoldText.Text);
     parameters.AddWithValue("@part",IPNText.Text);
     sda.Fill(dta);
}
```

You can store the connection string in your application's settings as a parameter of type `Connection String` to avoid hard-coding the connection string. This would allow you to access the connection string using the setting name

Comment: It says that it cannot convert query from 'string' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

Comment: Oops,  forgot to add the connection parameter

Comment: Ok but doing this It will allow the user to enter whatever Tool or Part number that they want and I want it to error out when the entered data is incorrect for either one.

Comment: This is no different than the original code.  If you want error handling, just wrap the code in an exception handler.  Validation should be performed before trying to load though.

Comment: What variable should I use as the exception handler. Also since I am extremely new to c# programing can you explain to me (briefly) how this code works.